# DeadlineExceededError only when starting new instance (using webapp2)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm getting some weird behavior -- when the application starts up a new instance for the first time, I get a DeadlineExceededError. When I hit refresh in the browser it works just fine And it doesn't matter which page I try. The strange thing is I can see all my debugging code just fine. In fact, I write to the log just prior to calling self.response and it shows up in the console's log. This is pretty hard to troubleshoot, since I'm not having any page load problems in the development environment, and the traceback is a bit opaque to me:

```
E 2013-09-29 00:10:03.975
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    for chunk in result:
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 1286, in appstats_wsgi_wrapper
    end_recording(status)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 1410, in end_recording
    rec.save()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 654, in save
    key, len_part, len_full = self._save()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py", line 678, in _save
    namespace=config.KEY_NAMESPACE)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py", line 1008, in set_multi
    namespace=namespace)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py", line 907, in _set_multi_with_policy
    status_dict = rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py", line 974, in __set_with_policy_hook
    rpc.check_success()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 578, in check_success
    self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 133, in CheckSuccess
    raise self.exception
DeadlineExceededError

I 2013-09-29 00:10:03.988
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

I'm not sure how to even go about debugging this, since the error seems to be after all my code has already run.

Edit: I should add this:

```
I 2013-09-29 00:09:06.919
  DEBUG: Writing output!
E 2013-09-29 00:10:03.975
```

You can see there's nearly a full minute between logging "Writing output!" just before self.response is called, and when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Deadlineexceedederror** happens in app engine, if any request to a frontend instance does not get a response within 60 seconds. So what is happening in your case must be that when there are no running instance and your app receives a new user request, a new instance is started for processing. This will lead to an overall `response time = instance startup time like library loading and initial data access + the time for processing the user request` and this causes a deadlineexceeded error. Then when you are accessing your app immediately , there is an already running instance and so `response time =  the time for processing the user request` and you do not get any error.

Please check the suggested approaches for [handling deadlineexceedederror](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors) including warmup requests, which is like keeping an instance ready before arrival of a live user request.

Comment: I read through that, but I'm not sure it applies. I'm not importing that many modules, and I'm not sure how warmup requests will help here, since this is happening when there are zero instances alive. (I'm currently testing with my users and there isn't much traffic yet.) There's also the fact that it's able to write to the log just fine, by which point all of my libraries have been loaded. If the max time is 60 seconds, I can deduce that my code is taking only 3 seconds to run, and it then times out after self.response has been called.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. I turned on warmup requests, which allowed me to set a minimum number of idle instances. I set it to 1, which now allows the page to load just fine. I still think it's a bit strange to need to do this since from what I can tell, my code only takes 3 seconds to run when first spinning up.

Comment: Turning on min idle instances masks the problem, since you don't spin up an instance.  You'll still hit this problem once in a while when load goes up and you need to spin up a new isntance.  At the very least, you're loading the appstats module.  Try disabling that to start.  It's also possible that the few modules you import indirectly import many other modules.